# how to remove borders in handwritten mnist data

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, ocr, mnist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhy4Q.png)

Like this image, I wanna remove the borders, but I dont know how to remove them,,
And how can I get an image with only values of 0 and 1 to have values of 0 to 255?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HunO.png)

I tried:
I put the numbers in the image in the center.
Compute the horizontal and vertical projection of every image.
Use Gaussian, Contour

Answer (score 0):

you can try `cv.HoughLines` and  `cv.HoughLinesP` see more examles in [open cv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)

```
lines = cv.HoughLines(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 150, None, 0, 0)
```